# Making query efficient

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have come across a query which, while working, is hard to understand(make changes) and in my opinioin is un-optimized.

```
SELECT cp.`order` AS `order`, cp.parent_id, cp.id AS category_id, cp.stub, cp.name as category_name, dc.deals_in_cat, d.*
    FROM category_parent cp,
    (
        SELECT id, title, subtitle, image, image_m, discount, itemid, price, new_price, catalog_id, property_id, seller_id, category FROM deals 
            WHERE deals.category = 1 
            AND itemid NOT IN (156785431) 
            ORDER BY e_order LIMIT 8
    ) d,
    (
        SELECT a.`id` AS parent_id, COUNT( DISTINCT c.`itemid` ) AS deals_in_cat
            FROM `category_parent` AS a 
            LEFT JOIN `navigation_filters_weightage` AS d ON a.`id` = d.`cat_id`, 
                `deals_parent_cat` AS b,
                `deals` AS c 
            WHERE a.`parent_id` = b.`id` 
            AND c.`category` = a.`id` GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY b.`order` ASC , a.`order` ASC
    ) AS dc
    WHERE cp.id = d.category 
    AND cp.active = '1' 
    AND dc.parent_id = cp.id;
```

Can you please suggest ways on making it more simpler.

Thanks

Comment: how do you know it is un-optimized? Does it take too long to run? Not using indexes? Without Table structure and query plan and without test data and expected result sets it is difficult to help

Comment: I know it might be difficult to suggest improvements without schema, but can't post it due to some restrictions. It takes longer to load. If it helps, the tables are normalized.

Comment: The query doesn't look bad at all. It's performance will depend on indexes that exist on the tables. Your first step is to look at the query plan. If you can't post that, then we're pretty much at a stop here; you'll have to learn about what query plans mean yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, indexes are probably a big factor for your query.

I would start by confirming you have at least the following indexes available

```
table            index
deals            (category, e_order, itemid )
category_parent  (active, id )
```

Typically, I would have the itemID before the order by since it is part of the WHERE clause, but since you are getting all EXCEPT one ID, I think the order-by clause column would help out more.

One additional note... Your "dc" query for getting counts is doing the counts for ALL entries, but your outer query is only considering "active=1".  I would add this qualifier in your "dc" query as well via

```
WHERE  a.Active='1' AND  -- rest of your criteria
```

Finally, being a website, doing counts on the fly repeatedly is always going to be a big performance hit.  As suggested in other posts and again here, you may be better off by adding a column to your category_parents table for "Deals_In_Cat" and have it updated via a trigger whenever any deals are added or removed.  This way, you get the count done ONCE when added/deleted, but all future references no longer requires the count being applied.  This will probably be the best thing you can apply for performance.